# Textbox value to allow only decimals and numbers using ng-pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

In my code I need to allow decimals and integers. How can I check this using `ng-pattern`?

**example code**

my test cases

1)22 = pass,

2)22.5 = pass,

3)2a = fail,

4)@#@ = fail

Comment: Try this regex: `\d*(\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 8):

`ng-pattern` takes a string.

The string is regex so give this a shot

```
/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/;
```

It allows decimal and whole numbers.

To check it works properly I pasted it into [this](https://regex101.com/)

You can also use it to check any modifications you would like to add.

Also as Tushar said you could have this

```
/^\d+([,.]\d+)?$/;
```

since \d is the same as [0-9] in regex.

Comment: No need of `g`: _global_ flag. You can also use `\d` as option to `[0-9]`

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, but it is not allowing the whole number, for ex: if i enter 22 it get fails

Comment: let me see about fixing that

Comment: I checked the regex with the online checker but couldn't get the fail. What is the error you get in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is also allows decimal and whole numbers.

```
/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/
```

Comment: how to disable value after 2 decimals and show invalid?